# Oracle Pass multiple rows or resultset of a SQL to a function as parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Is it possible to do create a function to take in a query result and do some processing and return me a pipeline table. If it works for a normal function, i can get it to work for pipelined. Its not called from a stored proc, so don't know how to use cursor in this scenario.

```
select SF_PROCESS_FUNCTION(
    select 'abcd' as keyVal, 'first value' as descVal from dual
    union
    select 'efgh' as keyVal, 'second value' as descVal from dual) from dual;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?9108-How-to-Pass-PL-SQL-Table-as-Input-Parameter

Comment: *do some processing* what kind of ??

Comment: @clinomaniac : I tried that approach, but i am not able to make it to work even from a plsql block

DECLARE
    testTyp Z_TEST_ROW_TBL := Z_TEST_ROW_TBL();
BEGIN
  select * into testTyp from (
        select 'abcd' as keyVal, 'first value' as descVal from dual
        union
        select 'efgh' as keyVal, 'second value' as descVal from dual
        );        
--SF_B_TEST_FN_WTIH_TBL(testVal);
DBMS_output.put_line('end:');
END;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably wrap the query using a `CURSOR` expression. Since you want it to be `PIPELINED`, you need to use `select * FROM TABLE()` syntax

```
select * FROM TABLE ( SF_PROCESS_FUNCTION(
CURSOR
 (
    select 'abcd' as keyVal, 'first value' as descVal from dual
    union
    select 'efgh' as keyVal, 'second value' as descVal from dual) 
) );
```

Your function should have a `SYS_REFCURSOR` as input argument.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
SF_PROCESS_FUNCTION (inpquery IN SYS_REFCURSOR) RETURN keydesc_typ 
    PIPELINED 
    AS
..
..
```